# How to track which entities\aggregates has changed and therefore should be persisted?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

Let's say I have some aggregates A and B. Aggregate A issues some event which aggregate B is subscribed to.

1. If B has not yet been instantiated by the time event was issued it will not process the event. In this case who's responsibility is to instantiate all aggregates that are listening to issued event?
2. After that all aggregates have processed the event, how can I know which of them changed so I can persist changes?

I would appreciate any links to working examples where these problems are solved

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate B cannot be subscribed by itself to the published event.

First you should consider an `EventBus` that subscribes to occuring events which should be handled after the transaction commits. The best place for handling transactions is an `ApplicationService`. Then the best solution in my opinion would be spreading the news to the local and remote bounded contexts interested in the event using a `MessageQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

> Aggregate A issues some event which aggregate B is subscribed to.

Aggregates receive commands and generate events. They can't receive events from other Aggregates. When we have business processes that span multiple Aggregates then we can use a [Saga/Process manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx): it receive relevant events from the Aggregates and it sends commands to other Aggregates.

> If B has not yet been instantiated by the time event was issued it will not process the event. In this case who's responsibility is to instantiate all aggregates that are listening to issued event?

The actual method of subscribing to events depends on the programming language and other things. In my current PHP project I use an `EventSubscriber` that uses a auto-generated map of `event` classes to `listener` classes (one `event` has zero or more `listeners`). This subscriber lives in the Application layer. This means that before it dispatches the event it must instantiate every listener and then sends the event to it. For instantiation it uses a [DIC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). [Here](https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-es) is more about this framework (disclaimer: it's mine).

> After that all aggregates have processed the event, how can I know which of them changed so I can persist changes?

Sending commands (not events - see my first paragraph) to Aggregates is the responsibility of the `CommandDispatcher`. This is an service from the Application layer that after it sends a command then it collects all events and persist them *atomically* (all or none) in the `EventStore` using an `AggregateRepository`.

But things can and will go wrong in between. Thats why we also need other components that keep track of event dispatching. I use an `SagaEventTracker` that knows what events were dispatched to what Sagas and if they were succesfully dispatched or not. This works best in combination with making the Aggregates command methods to be idempotent because you can send them the same commands more than once without them throwing exception (even if the Aggregate is not idempotent you could use a *silenced* version of the `CommandDispatcher` in Sagas).